# How to get table schema from Progress database via odbc

Tags: schema, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a linked server set up between sql 2008 and a Progress OpenEdge 10.1b server.

How do I get the table schemas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get all available tables:

```
select * from sysprogress.SYSTABLES;
```

or

```
select * from sysprogress.SYSTABLES_FULL;
```

You can get all columns of specified table:

```
select * from sysprogress.SYSCOLUMNS where TBL = 'table_name';
```

or

```
select * from sysprogress.SYSCOLUMNS_FULL where TBL = 'table_name';
```

It works only with DBA privileged user.

More detail in OpenEdge Product Documentation: https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview

Document title: **SQL Reference**

Chapter: **OpenEdge SQL System Catalog Tables**

Answer (score 2):

You can do a statement like

`SELECT * FROM LinkedProgressOpenedgeServer.YourDatabase.Owner.TableName WHERE 1=2`

That should return just the schema without any data.

Answer (score -1):

Normally the default schema name is PUB. You can try using PUB schema.